# How to create new files from range

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create new files (in the same folder) from sheet "lista strategiczna".D2 only if doesn't exist. Next offset one position down, and create next files etc. What I doing wrong?

```
Sub TworzenieZamowien()
    Dim thisWb As Workbook
    Dim nazwaPliku As String
    Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim aktywnaKomorka As Range
    Set aktywnaKomorka = Sheets("lista strategiczna").Range("D2")
    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path, vbDirectory)
      Do Until aktywnaKomorka = ""
      nazwaPliku = thisWb.Path & "\Zamówienie " & aktywnaKomorka & ".xls"
        If FilePath <> nazwaPliku Then
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=nazwaPliku
        ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        aktywnaKomorka.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Else
        aktywnaKomorka.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
      Loop  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set your range at the start, use a For loop and do away with selecting things (rarely a good idea). Your current code doesn't change `aktywnaKomorka`(it remains D2), you just activate the next cell below but your loop does not reference the active cell.

```
Sub TworzenieZamowien()

Dim thisWb As Workbook
Dim nazwaPliku As String
Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim aktywnaKomorka As Range

With Sheets("lista strategiczna")
    Set aktywnaKomorka = .Range("D2", .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

Dim FilePath As String, r As Range

FilePath = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path, vbDirectory)

For Each r In aktywnaKomorka
    If r <> vbNullString Then
        nazwaPliku = thisWb.Path & "\Zamówienie " & r & ".xls"
        If FilePath <> nazwaPliku Then
            Workbooks.Add
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=nazwaPliku
            ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        End If
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

If you wanted to persist with your Do loop rather than Select add this line

```
set aktywnaKomorka=aktywnaKomorka.Offset(1, 0)
```